# Finding the interval in a random variable

Tags: probability

I need to find `a` in the interval $[1,a]$ with $a>1$ of a random variable with with a continuous uniform distribution, the only thing I was given is that $E(X) = 6Var(X)$, how can I approach this problem?

$$f_X(x)  = \begin{cases}
\frac 1 {(a-1)}&\text{for $1 \leq x\leq a$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

Now by properties of variance we have:

\begin{align}
6 Var (X) = Var(\sqrt6 X)
\end{align}

But I think I'm not going anywhere with this, can anyone give me a hint on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Start by writing out what you know. The mean will be at $\mu = (1 + a)/2$, and you know the variance is $\text{var} = (a - 1)^{-1} \int_1^a (x - \mu)^2\ dx$. If $\mu = 6 \text{var}$ what does that tell you about $a$? (Integrate and solve for $a$.)

Comment: Am I worg if I only take the $\mu$ formula for the uniform distribution and solve for $a$, is not a value but an equation for $a$ right? Or is completely necessary to solve that integral to know the value of $a$?

Comment: Danny, the only thing you know about the value of the mean in this problem is that, whatever $a$ is, it turns out that $\mu = 6 \text{var}$. Both $\mu$ and $\text{var}$ will involve $a$, so you'll have to solve for it.

Comment: I solved it as you said but I got $a=1$, but by definition $a>1$ did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check your work, good practice. Here's what I'm seeing:
\begin{align}
\text{mean} &= (1 + a)/2, \\
\text{var} &= (a - 1)^2 / 12.
\end{align}
So if you happen to know $\text{mean} = 6\, \text{var}$, it
has to be the case that $(1 + a)/2 = 6 (a - 1)^2/12$. ($a = 3$.)